# Incet (edge loops or support loops) when bevel like in 3ds max

Tags: modifiers, edges, geometry, bevel

3ds max has option to incet edges when you bevel them. It used to get the same effect like harden normals but with geometry. It automatically add an edge loop on every side of beveled edge.
[image]

In my project i cant use harden normals so i need this option. Adding edge loops not a problem with simple geometry but when you need to do them in dozens of complex objects its very time consuming. Is there a way to make use of bevel modifier that way? Or is there a way in blender to make it al least a bit easier? Maybe addon?

Comment: Have you tried adding a bevel modifier with the Segments set to 2? Try reducing the Amount until you get the result you need.

Comment: No, it does not work that way. Segement amount does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a similar topology to the 3DS bevel-with-inset by using 2 consecutive *Bevel* modifiers.. the first set to 2 segments, an the second to 1:

[image: Bevel]

Here, the default 'Superellipse' profile is used, by angle, with the 'Shape' setting in the first modifier and the 'Angle' setting in the second modifier tweaked, to catch the right edges.

Tweaking to catch different edges can change the topology:

[image]

However, this is all angle dependent, it may not suit.

Modifiers can be copied from the active to all other selected objects, from the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> menu.